# Transforming this into an expression

Tags: scheme

[image]

Hi guys i'm wanted to know if i have the correct expression for this picture, if not why please

```
(a((f(b c))(g h))e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but not quite right. It'll be more clear if we build the list structure explicitly using `cons`; this is more like it:

```
(cons 'a
      (cons (cons (cons 'f 
                        (cons 'b 'c))
                  (cons 'g
                        (cons 'h '())))
            (cons 'e '())))

=> '(a ((f b . c) g h) e)
```

Notice that in this part: `(f b . c)` we have an *improper list*, because the sublist doesn't end in `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You answer is incorrect as it doesn't properly express the improper list `(f b . c)`. Also the parentheses around `g h` are an error.

With *dotted pairs* the full expression would be:

```
'(a ((f b . c) g h) e)
```

Note that  `'(f b . c)` is not the same as `'(f (b c))`.

See that `'(f (b c))` is:

```
(cons 'f (cons (cons 'b (cons 'c '())) '()))
```

Rather than what `'(f b . c)` is:

```
(cons 'f (cons (cons 'b 'c) '()))
```

Note the improper list.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of cons :)